# tense: "are" or "were"

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

Is the present tense "are" properly used in the following?
Why wasn't "were" used instead?

> "And it makes sense, up to a point, to debate ending remedies for discrimination that **are** more appropriate to mid-20th century America, where nearly 90 percent of the population was white and racism kept blacks, Latinos and Jews from advancing in the workplace."

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The fact that the reference is to ***ending*** these "remedies for discrimination" implies they're still in force. So even though "mid-20th century America" no longer "exists" in the real world (that's now something in the *past*), you could still talk about what those remedies ***are*** appropriate to. Having said that, I think both tenses are fine, and I personally would go with ***were*** to emphasize the clearly intended implication that even though those remedies still exist, *they're outdated, and should be discarded*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those remedies **are** suited to mid-20th century America. The remedies still exist, conceptually, and indeed are presumably still in place, given there's apparently debate about ending them.

**Were** could be used as well, because the remedies existed in the past as well as now. *Are* would not be appropriate if they had already ended. If they had never been put into place, but were ideas that had been discussed or suggested, then *are* would be appropriate.